# ODBC DataStage read nvarchar from SQL Server error

Tags: odbc, collation, datastage

I use DataStage to transform data. I read a column nvarchar from SQL server 2008. However,  the job got error "External table: count of bad input rows reached maxerrors limit". When I remove the column with nvarchar type the job run normally.

When I view data sample in datastage the sample character turn to "?: like the picture below. In the SQL server, this column has collation : SQL_Latin1_general_100_CP1_CI_AS.

Version ODBC driver is 6.1.7

[image]

Answer (score 0):

NVARCHAR can hold unicode data and when you transfer it to a Latin1 codepage there could be problems mapping some special characters to that.
I suggest you try specifying the extended attribute "unicode" in the column definition.
A second try could be to specify unicode as the job codepage.
Also a combination of above steps could be worth a try.

It also depends on your target - where you want your data to be transferred to.